# XCode - how to set a path variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on a XCode project, and the header and library search paths are defined as follows :
`"$(COMMON)/MyLibrary"`
`"$(COMMON)/OtherLibrary"`

Where can I set in XCode the value of the `COMMON` variable so that it points to the right folders on my machine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you please try the following step?

> Go to **Target**->**Build Settings**->**Add Build Setting**(at bottom right)->**Add
>   User-Defined Setting**->Name it COMMON->And add the path for it as
>   value. And check now.